# What is the reading limit of function 'read' in 'unistd.h'?

Tags: file, unix, io

Standard unix C has this function:

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

But what is the maximum bytes that this 'read' function can read 1 time?

Comment: @Tomalak: The question is about neither language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it can read as many bytes as there are available in `buf`. In reality, the underlying device driver (be it the filesystem or the network, or a pipe), would return less than what you want in case there is nothing more available.

So, the particular behaviour of `read` depends on the underlying driver in the kernel.

This is why it's important to always check the return value of `read` and examine the *actual* bytes read.

Comment: "This is why it's important to always check the return value of read and examine the actual bytes read." however note that this is not always helpful: some systems will return EINVAL if the value is too large for their tastes. Notably macOS will EINVAL on any read value larger than 2^31-1, even on 64b systems.

Answer (score 11):

From [`man read(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read):

> `read()` attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd into
>   the buffer starting at buf.
>
> If count is zero, `read()` returns zero and has no other results. **If
>   count is greater than `SSIZE_MAX`, the result is unspecified.**

The value of `SSIZE_MAX` depends on your system, but generally it's something akin to the maximum value of `signed long`, which is often 2<sup>31</sup> (32-bit systems) or 2<sup>63</sup> (64-bit systems).

2<sup>31</sup> bytes is 2 gigabytes, so you're probably safe; in practice, the actual device driver/buffers/network I/O is never going to give you a 2 gigabyte chunk of data in one go.

Answer (score 4):

quote from IEEE Std 1003.1 (aka POSIX.1)

> If the value of nbyte is greater than {SSIZE_MAX}, the result is implementation-defined.

So you have to check `man 2 read` at your target platform. For example, FreeBSD man says in ERRORS part:

> [EINVAL]           The value nbytes is greater than INT_MAX.

Comment: Of note: this was an error already back in 2019. [Back in 2013](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/commit/sys/kern/sys_generic.c?id=cd4dd444ddcc0e3d0c2c8bdef996403a9772863b) the io subsystem was updated to use SSIZE_MAX by default (the sysctl was added [18 months earlier](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/commit/sys/kern/sys_generic.c?id=526d0bd547574b185147f03c13e2db7abe566a08) but initially enabled by default).

Comment: The manpage for `write(2)` took some time to be updated (it was only updated in 11.2 that I can see) and the manpage for `read(2)` still hasn't been fixed but [it was recently reported](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=276937).

Answer (score 1):

> read() takes an open file descriptor, the address of a buffer, and a
>   number, count of bytes. It attempts to read count bytes into the
>   buffer from the file described by the descriptor. It is important to
>   assure that buf points to at least count bytes of storage!

It can read as much as your buffer can hold, the limit is SSIZE_MAX and also the limits of your hardware.

Comment: You can't ask for more than SIZE_MAX bytes, and since you probably want to know how much you actually managed to read (and follow the spec), you're limited to SSIZE_MAX bytes.

Comment: @janne: but SIZE_MAX is 0xFFFF'FFFF (VC++)! you really mean that number?

Comment: @Paul: `SIZE_MAX` != `SSIZE_MAX`.

Comment: anyway, 'signed' or 'unsigned', this *_MAX is still a 32 bit number, terribly large for regular file. it's really good if possible to read up to *_MAX bytes!